# Retrieving Users using Backendess

Tags: java, android, backend, backendless

Has anyone used Backendless as their backend for their app. I had a look in their documentation and I was not able to find documentation on how to return users from registered users.

https://backendless.com/documentation

Answer (score 0):

You retrieve users from Users table with simple data query, read doc [here](https://backendless.com/documentation/data/android/data_basic_search.htm).

Comment: Ah I missed that, Thank you thats perfect!